# Script for fixing broken hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a spreadsheet that is used for tracking work orders. The first column of the sheet has numbers starting at 14-0001 and continue sequentially all the way down. The numbers were hyperlinked to the .XLS of their respective work order (ex. the cell containing 14-0001 links to Z:\WorkOrders\14-0001-Task Name\14-0001-Task Name.xls)

Problem is, My computer crashed and when Excel recovered the file all the hyperlinks changed from:

```
**"Z:\blah blah\WorkOrders\14-****-Task Name\14-****-Task Name.xls"**
```

to

```
**"C:\Users\blahblah\WorkOrders\14-****-Task Name\14-****-Task Name.xls"**
```

There are hundreds of entries so I was hoping that I could run a script to fix all of the hyperlinks.

Heres a script I found online which from what I understood is supposed to do what I want, but when I run the script from the VB window in Excel I get "Compile error: Argument not optional" and it highlights `Sub CandCHyperlinx()`

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CandCHyperlinx()

Dim cel As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim adr As String
Dim delstring As String

 'string to delete: CHANGE ME!  (KEEP quotes!)
delstring = "C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\"

 'get all cells as range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

 'ignore non hyperlinked cells
On Error Resume Next

 'check every cell
For Each cel In rng
     'skip blank cells
    If cel <> "" Then
         'attempt to get hyperlink address
        adr = cel.Hyperlinks(1).Address
         'not blank? then correct it, is blank get next
        If adr <> "" Then
             'delete string from address
            adr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(adr, delstring)
             'put new address
            cel.Hyperlinks(1).Address = adr
             'reset for next pass
            adr = ""
        End If
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Is this even the right script? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Substitute` is whats highlighted with the error and that's because it takes three arguments not two.  [See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194878%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for more info.  Try this: `adr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(adr, delstring, "C:\Users\")`

Comment: @pnuts I thought that too but `Find` didn't work on hyperlink addresses, or I should say, it didn't work outside of VBA.

Comment: Yeah like @PortlandRunner said the Find/Replace tool wont touch the hyperlink addresses.
I tried adding the third argument, and now I dont get an error! BUT, It seems to have done nothing to the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Const FIND_TXT As String = "C:\" 'etc
    Const NEW_TXT As String = "Z:\"  'etc

    Dim rng As Range, hl As Hyperlink

    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells

        If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
            Set hl = rng.Hyperlinks(1)
            Debug.Print rng.Address(), "Before", hl.TextToDisplay, hl.Address
            hl.TextToDisplay = Replace(hl.TextToDisplay, FIND_TXT, NEW_TXT)
            hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, FIND_TXT, NEW_TXT)
            Debug.Print rng.Address(), "After", hl.TextToDisplay, hl.Address
        End If

    Next rng


End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and still get no results. When i click Run the window flashes for a split second and then nothing. No errors, no fixed HLs. Is there a way to view a log of some sort that would show whats happening when I click Run?

Comment: Check the Immediate pane in the VB Editor - there should be output there if any hyperlinks were found.

Comment: Okay so in the Immediate pane, It lists all of the hyperlinks AFTER 14-0040. Meaning the first 40 HLs it did not find. And this is what the output looked like for every record:

    `$B$49         Before        14-0046       ../AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel/Work-Orders/Completed/14-0046-WO-LN7-550 Luxfer Tank Fitting/14-0046-WO-LN7-550 Luxfer Tank Fitting-Completed.pdf` 

`$B$49         After         14-0046       ../AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel/Work-Orders/Completed/14-0046-WO-LN7-550 Luxfer Tank Fitting/14-0046-WO-LN7-550 Luxfer Tank Fitting-Completed.pdf`

Comment: Looks like those paths are relative? Is that what you see if you go to edit the hyperlink manually?

Comment: I didn't even notice that, doh!  I think I got it. My problem was I wasn't putting the ".." in front of the path. And after running it a few times (some were relative, some weren't) I think I finally got it. Oh and for some reason it didn't like "Z:\" so I replaced it with the actual drive name "\\goddard\" and it all worked out. Now I just have to pull it off on the original copy.

Comment: c:\ and Z:\ were just examples to illustrate the method - I should maybe have added a comment that you should replace those with your actual values...

Comment: No I got that part. The paths in the OP were examples because the actual links are pretty long. It took a few tries to get everything right, as there were several different erroneous paths for the HLs, but in the end it worked! I removed some parts of your script so that it would only list all the HL paths in the Immediate window without actually changing them in order for me to verify nothing else was getting trashed. I find it pretty absurd that excel does this when it recovers a file, but at least now I know how to fix it if ti ever happens again.
  Thanks @Tim Williams you helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, and all the macros I tried didn't work for me. This one is adapted from Tim's above and from this thread [Office Techcentre thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9f09d661-d355-4dcd-95e2-9df7c1495396/excel-2010-changes-links-from-network-location-to-local-user-appdata-on-opening-a-2003-file?referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9f09d661-d355-4dcd-95e2-9df7c1495396/excel-2010-changes-links-from-network-location-to-local-user-appdata-on-opening-a-2003-file?forum=excel). In my case, all my hyperlinks were in column B, between rows 3 and 400 and 'hidden' behind the filename, and I wanted to put the links back to my Dropbox folder where they belong.

```
Sub FixLinks3()

Dim intStart As Integer

Dim intEnd As Integer

Dim strCol As String

Dim hLink As Hyperlink

intStart = 2

intEnd = 400

strCol = "B"


For i = intStart To intEnd

    For Each hLink In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    hLink.TextToDisplay = Replace (hLink.TextToDisplay, "AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel",
    "Dropbox/References")
    hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel", 
    "Dropbox/References")
    Next hLink

    Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help, Tim!